# Multiple math mode lines in a row?

Tags: math-mode

Is there a way to have multiple math mode lines in a row without doing anything fancy? This is what I want, shown below. There isn't any extra space and the equations all appear with normal indentation:

[image]

This was achieved using this ugly code, involving a new paragraph per equation:

```
Three solutions to $3x + 5y = 1$:

$t = 1: (7, -4)$

$t = 2: (12, -7)$
          
$t = -1: (12, -7)$
```

I saw one solution suggest the `align*` environment with `&` in front of everything, but that results in extra indentation, shown below:

[image]

I'm a bit surprised I've been stuck on this since this sounds so basic. Am I missing something obvious? Thanks for reading.

Comment: align is centred by default, if you want flush left displays use `[fleqn]` (and set `\mathindent` to zero)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Setting `\mathindent` did the trick, thanks so much! I knew about `[fleqn]` as an option for the `amsmath` or `mathtools` package (and using that alone didn't really work well), but I didn't know there was a natural indentation for math stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`align` is centred by default, if you want flush left displays use `[fleqn]` (and set `\mathindent` to zero)